# cmake changing option does not result in recompilation

Tags: cmake

I got the following problem:

I got a CMakeLists.txt including the following line:

```
option(SCALAR_SINGLE_PRECISION "Use float as scalar" OFF)
```

I would expect that this would result in recompilation when I switch the option (and configure and build after that), but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print the option value using message(..) to confirm the behavior ?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai I tried: `MESSAGE(STATUS "SCALAR_SINGLE_PRECISION:         " ${SCALAR_SINGLE_PRECISION} )` right after the option, but I'm unsure where this is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing that the option itself has no influence on the compilation. So I need to add:

option(SCALAR_SINGLE_PRECISION "Use float as scalar" OFF)
add_definitions( -DSCALAR_SINGLE_PRECISION=${SCALAR_SINGLE_PRECISION} )

I'm no expert to cmake so if anyone knows better please correct me.